# How to struct array in nested json object with the same keys

Tags: json, go, zabbix

I am creating host objects in Zabbix via microservices in Golang. I have to serve the following json to 
the Zabbix api to create host which is part of multiple groups

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "host.create",
  "params": {
    "host": "TEST-HOST",
    "interfaces": [
      {
        "type": 2,
        "main": 1,
        "useip": 1,
        "ip": "0.0.0.0",
        "dns": "",
        "port": "10050"
      }
    ],
    "groups": [
      {
        "groupid": "33"
      },
      {
        "groupid": "27"
      }
    ],
    "templates": [
      {
        "templateid": "12156"
      }
    ],
    "inventory_mode": 0
  },
  "auth": "example_token",
  "id": 1
}
```

This code returns the json object where the groups array is empty.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Zabbix struct {
    Jsonrpc string `json:"jsonrpc"`
    Method  string `json:"method"`
    Params  Params `json:"params"`
    Auth    string `json:"auth"`
    ID      int    `json:"id"`
}
type Groups struct {
    Groupid  string `json:"groupid"`
    Groupid1 string `json:"groupid"`
}
type Templates struct {
    Templateid string `json:"templateid"`
}
type Inventory struct {
    Type        string `json:"type"`
    Tag         string `json:"tag"`
    TypeFull    string `json:"type_full"`
    MacaddressA string `json:"macaddress_a"`
    MacaddressB string `json:"macaddress_b"`
    SerialA     string `json:"serialno_a"`
    SerialB     string `json:"serialno_b"`
}
type Params struct {
    Host          string       `json:"host"`
    Interfaces    []Interfaces `json:"interfaces"`
    Groups        []Groups     `json:"groups"`
    Templates     []Templates  `json:"templates"`
    InventoryMode int          `json:"inventory_mode"`
    Inventory     Inventory    `json:"inventory"`
}
type Interfaces struct {
    Type  int    `json:"type"`
    Main  int    `json:"main"`
    Useip int    `json:"useip"`
    IP    string `json:"ip"`
    DNS   string `json:"dns"`
    Port  string `json:"port"`
}

func main() {

    jsonobj := &Zabbix{
        Jsonrpc: "2.0",
        Method:  "host.create",
        Params: Params{
            Host: "OBU_TEST_123",
            Interfaces: []Interfaces{
                {
                    Type:  2,
                    Main:  1,
                    Useip: 1,
                    IP:    "10.10.10.10",
                    DNS:   "",
                    Port:  "10050",
                },
            },
            Groups: []Groups{
                {
                    Groupid:  "27",
                    Groupid1: "33",
                },
            },
            Templates: []Templates{
                {
                    Templateid: "12156",
                },
            },
            Inventory: Inventory{
                Type:        "On Board Unit",
                Tag:         "test",
                TypeFull:    "test",
                MacaddressA: "test",
                MacaddressB: "test",
                SerialA:     "test",
                SerialB:     "test",
            },
            InventoryMode: 0,
        },
        Auth: "test-token",
        ID:   1,
    }

    byteArray, err := json.Marshal(jsonobj)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Print(bytes.NewBuffer(byteArray).String())

}
```

The output:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "host.create",
  "params": {
    "host": "OBU_TEST_123",
    "interfaces": [
      {
        "type": 2,
        "main": 1,
        "useip": 1,
        "ip": "10.10.10.10",
        "dns": "",
        "port": "10050"
      }
    ],
    "groups": [
      {}
    ],
    "templates": [
      {
        "templateid": "12156"
      }
    ],
    "inventory_mode": 0,
    "inventory": {
      "type": "On Board Unit",
      "tag": "test",
      "type_full": "test",
      "macaddress_a": "test",
      "macaddress_b": "test",
      "serialno_a": "test",
      "serialno_b": "test"
    }
  },
  "auth": "test-token",
  "id": 1
}
```

What i am missing? Is there any more elegant way to create such a big json object instead of using structs?

Comment: In `Groups` both fields have same `json` tag field name, that ain't good. Just have `Groups` have one `Groupid` field and instantiate the slice with the values instead of one.

Comment: ... example: https://play.golang.com/p/avniaXz4rVe

Comment: `Groups` is an array of objects with a single integer field named `groupid`. That is not what you implemented.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/PDqAOY0lTUI this is another way. However it's not a good practice in go the use of interface if you are sure of the model, as in this case.

Answer (score -1):

type Groups struct {
    Groupid  string `json:"groupid"`
    Groupid1 string `json:"groupid"`
}

groupid - Cannot be the same value for both. Change it as follows and it should work.
type Groups struct {
    Groupid  string `json:"groupid"`
    Groupid1 string `json:"groupid1"`
}

Answer (score -1):

```
type Groups struct {
    Groupid  string `json:"groupid"`
    Groupid1 string `json:"groupid"`
}
```

groupid - Cannot be the same value for both. Change it as follows and it should work.

```
type Groups struct {
    Groupid  string `json:"groupid"`
    Groupid1 string `json:"groupid1"`
}
```

Comment: This is not what the achievement is. In your solution the second key is different. Which means the Zabbix api will reject the request.